# HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 409 Too many requests

Tags: php, simplexml, http-1.1

I'm using simplexml in my code and it worked well since yesterday, now i have this message: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 409 Too many requests

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a problem in your code, but on the server which you're calling. You seem to have exceeded one of its limits for the number of API/HTTP requests.

Comment: I love a strict firewall.

Comment: any ideas how to resolve without change my code? tks
by the way, the site is: www.autofave.com.br

Comment: I don't think you can solve it by changing your code at all.. talk to the server administrator..

Comment: The server said that i need change my code to put only one request per minute

Comment: Well then, you'll have to let me know why you're calling the server, i.e. What does it do?